# Quickblox message sent time issue in cross platfom (Web and Mobile)

Tags: javascript, php, web, chat, quickblox

I had Integrated Quickblox chat application for both mobile and web,
now we have following case.

I am using quickblox Javascript SDK.

If mobile user have set his clock 1 hour ago to actual time, 
Now someone from web send him message, then to mobile user it will show "Message sent 1 hour ago" instead of "1 minute ago"

Because as per his mobile clock time difference is 1 hour, and actual message sent 1 minute ago.

I go through the documentation, but nothing found related to this issue,

I tried to add a custom parameter "time" in its JavaScript library's send and retrieve message functions, and the value of "time" is in UTC millisecond.

But nothing change in result.

So, how can I overcome to this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You must have to create a class for custom parameters, then and then custom parameters are worked.after creating a class you have you able to send and receive custom parameters and the second way is to pass extra parameters when a message send or receive, like using javascript when you send any message then you can add extra parameters into `extension`  you can add extra parameter on it and receive it on other end.